# i used sprintf() then too cant apply system() for cp a file

Tags: c, linux

```
char str[256]="cp /home/anup/unix_arch/w1.c /home/anup/Desktop/work.c";
    sprintf(buf, "/bin/sh -c %s", str);
     system(buf);
```

gives a error to `see the cp --help` and I'm unable to figure it out!

If i do system("vim wave.c"), it displays a vim distibutors introductory page

If i do system("rm wave.c"), it says to see again `rm --help`.

Please help me to find the problem     and      mainly,
i want to execute shell commands (copy) int the c program

Please  anybody brainstorm me .

Comment: Remove the `/bin/sh -c`. It's nonsense; the `system` function already runs the command via a shell, and if anything running through a shell is a bad thing, not a good thing. Running through 2 shells will make the situation even worse.

Answer (score 2):

Here's some brainstorming for you. All those results seem to indicate that you're only passing the first argument to your `system` command. `cp` on its own will tell you to look at the help, `vim` on its own gives you the Vim welcome screen and so on.

So:

1. How are you constructing those strings? Is it via `strcpy/strcat`?
2. If you print out the first four bytes of your `cp` command, what do you see?

The reason I ask the first is because you're *probably* constructing the string bit-by-bit so you can put in specific file names. If for some reason the string is `"cp\0source dest"` (with an embedded null), `system` will see only `cp`.

The second question should clarify that for sure.

Try thee following program to see if it prints in short or long format:

```
#include<stdlib.h>
int main (void) {
    system ("ls -al");
    return 0;
}
```

You *should* get something like:

```
total 21
drwxrwxrwt+ 1 pax None     0 2010-11-05 11:38 .
drwxrwxrwt+ 1 pax root     0 2010-10-28 11:22 ..
-rw-------  1 pax None 15815 2010-11-04 16:33 .bash_history
-rw-r--r--  1 pax None    29 2010-11-03 14:05 .bash_profile
-rw-------  1 pax None   191 2010-11-04 16:33 .history
-rw-------  1 pax None    68 2010-11-04 16:15 .lesshst
drwxrwxrwt+ 1 pax None     0 2010-10-28 11:22 .texmf
-rw-r--r--  1 pax None    38 2010-10-29 10:30 qq.awk
-rw-r--r--  1 pax None    97 2010-11-05 11:38 qq.c
-rwxr-xr-x  1 pax None 17790 2010-11-05 11:38 qq
-rw-r--r--  1 pax None   120 2010-11-04 10:18 qq.py
```

Comment: yes  what u said is absolute !     and  ur guess of my implimentation is also the same       so   what should i do if i want to impliment   plz  help me , at least u can say me what else to do

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have a correct path for the source and the destination? It seems you have a valid syntax.

You can try other C api, such as fopen, then create another file and write the contents of the opened file to the new created file using fwrite.

Comment: yes , i realized it now     it can be done with file functions